# SuiteCrm: drop down values does not show in the list

Tags: php, file-permissions, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I created two custom drop down fields in meeting module using studio and added  it to QuickCreate view. Field names are `"meeting_type_c"` & `"appointment_value_c"` and Drop Down List names are `"meetings_types_list"` & `"appointment_value_list"` respectively.

I can't see drop down lists in while creating meeting record. If I do "Quick Repair and Rebuild", I can see items in the list but after some time, items disappears. To show items in the list, I have to do "Quick Repair and Rebuild" again.

This is working on local server(wamp) perfectly but not on demo server(debian).

I am using Suite Crm Version 7.7.4.

I also changed permissions manually in the following way:

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .`

`sudo chmod -R 755 .`

`sudo chmod -R 775 cache custom modules themes data upload config_override.php`

Before Quick Repair and Rebuild:

[image: Before Quick Repair and Rebuild R]

After Quick Repair and Rebuild

[image: After Quick Repair and Rebuild]

Comment: have a look at this link(https://support.sugarcrm.com/Knowledge_Base/Platform_Management/Setting_Default_File_Permissions_and_Ownership_Via_config.php/index.html) and make sure this part is also working on your demo server.

Comment: Thanks @Star for sharing this info, I have made changes as per the document. will check after some time.

Comment: that trick did not work.

Comment: This is seems server issue as cache files are not generating with proper permission. have you checked .htaccess and it contain correct code?

Comment: @Star I did not make any changes in `.htaccess` file. it is same as earlier. Do I need to rebuild .htacces file via Repair?

Comment: yes execute it via admin interface and then check its contents. after executing repair and rebuild set permission to proper level and test it again.

Answer (score 0):

Please Install the package Outright_utils, include_once "custom/outright_utils/outright_final/outright_includes.php"; and call the function outright_do_repair(); in post_install.php in the package.
when you install the package this function automatically repair in the background.
package link  [here you have many other functions to make life easy](https://github.com/Ashish-Outright/outright_utils)

[see here for post install format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iL1V7.png)